# Julia: Run an external process for a given amount of time and capture its output

Tags: julia, timeout

I want to run an external process in Julia for a given amount of time (say 10 seconds) and capture its output.
I tried something like `` readchomp(`timeout 5 sleep 10`) ``  (substitute `sleep 10` by an arbitrary external process). However, a ProcessFailedException is thrown if the process was killed by `timeout` and I can not read the output of the program it produced until it was killed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`run` only throws an exception if `wait = true` (which it is by default). You'll want to set that kwarg to false and then manually `wait` on the process, while redirecting `stdout` to e.g. an `IOBuffer` via `pipeline`:

```
shell> cat loop.sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}; do
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done


julia> b = IOBuffer()
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> p = run(pipeline(`timeout 5 ./loop.sh`, stdout = b), wait = false); wait(p)

julia> p
Process(`timeout 5 ./loop.sh`, ProcessExited(124))

julia> String(take!(b))
"1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n"
```